# alarm takes n multiple times

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I am trying to make an alarm application that will take ‘n’ number of times from the user and buzz at those times and stores the difference in the timing so that the next user accesses the application, the stored difference is default. Here is the code of the main activity:

```
public void startAlert(View view) {
        EditText textH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hours);
        int h = Integer.parseInt(textH.getText().toString());

        EditText textM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(textM.getText().toString());

        EditText textS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
        int s = Integer.parseInt(textS.getText().toString());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, h);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, s);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I have no idea how to add n number of `editTexts` at the runtime? and for the `AlarmManager` class...shall i run a loop for creating n number of `AlarmManager` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a reference to the listView/layout in your activity. Then you can use layout.addView(editText)

It is pretty much the same as [Add button to a layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907609/add-button-to-a-layout-programmatically)

Simon

Comment: and how do i store the difference in the timings for future reference?

Comment: you could use a sqlite database on the phone, or just write them to a file on the phone