# Dynamically Adding buttons at run time

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm here because I want to be able to add buttons when some variable in my code change its value, and the only way I know to create a button is using a XML file, which is something I made previously when I know exactly all variables of the button. But I want similar buttons that do similar things but are not quite the same, and to bind variables of the button to each entry of a database. So, the question is: how can I create a button without a XML file?

Comment: have you tried to google it?

Comment: yes, and found some answers, sorry, new to stack overflow, it is my first question here, and I see that I am making a lot of mistakes, but... well, I'll try some of what I found, refine my question if needed and ask again. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
Button btn = new Button();
```

and then u can use their attributes to set text and value or perform operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
//the layout in which you want to add the button
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_lin_layout);

//create the button
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btn.setText("Send");
btn.setId(the_id_with_which_you_will_access_your_button);

//add the button to your layout
layout.addView(btn);
```

Or try with some of these answers:

[Android: programmatically adding buttons to a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710200/android-programmatically-adding-buttons-to-a-layout)

[How do I programmatically add buttons into layout one by one in several lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195056/how-do-i-programmatically-add-buttons-into-layout-one-by-one-in-several-lines)

[Add button to a layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907609/add-button-to-a-layout-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like following:

```
// create button dynamically
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("New Btn");

// find linerar layout from your view
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_layout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// add button in your layout
ll.addView(btn , lp);
```